# Python Beatiful Soup (Select only the one class with same name)

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to parse through elements of an email and I have successfully been able to extract the links from a button from the email. However, the class name on the button  appears twice in the email HTML, therefore extracting/ printing two links. I only need one the first link or reference to the class first with the same name.
This is my code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(msg.html, 'html.parser')
for link in soup('a', class\_='mcnButton', href=True):
print(link\['href'\])
```

The 'mcnButton' is referencing two html buttons within the email containing two seperate links.I only need the first reference to the 'mcnButton' class and link containing.
The above codes prints out two links (again I only need the first).

https://leemarpet.us10.list-manage.com/track/XXXXXXX1

https://leemarpet.us10.list-manage.com/track/XXXXXXX2

I figured there should be a way to index and separately access the first reference to the class and link. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!
I tried the select_one, find, and attempts to index the class, unfortunately resulted in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

To find only the first element matching your pattern use `.find()`:

```
soup.find('a', class_='mcnButton', href=True)
```

and to get its `href`:

```
soup.find('a', class_='mcnButton', href=True).get('href')
```

For more information check the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)